# assign nmap output to several variables

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, nmap

I am using nmap to scan my network and want to show every device that is up. 
The following works great:

```
ips=$(nmap -sn 192.168.1.68/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2, $3}')
```

What I now want to to is to save every output in a seperate variable.

Lets say `ips` give this output:

```
$ echo "$ips"
xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)
xxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)
xxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)
```

I now want to save (device1) in `var1`,(device2) in `var2` and (device3) in `var3`

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a bunch of separate scalar variables, just save the command output in an array instead of a scalar variable and then you'll be able to access it as `ips[0]`, `ips[1]`, etc. Using `printf` instead of your current `nmap | awk` pipeline for simplicity to reproduce your exact command output:

```
$ printf 'xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)\nxxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)\nxxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)\n'
xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)
xxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)
xxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)

$ ips=$(printf 'xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)\nxxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)\nxxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)\n')

$ echo "$ips"
xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)
xxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)
xxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)

$ readarray -t -d $'\n' ips < <(printf 'xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)\nxxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)\nxxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)\n')

$ declare -p ips
declare -a ips=([0]="xxx.xxx.x.1 (device1)" [1]="xxx.xxx.x.2 (device2)" [2]="xxx.xxx.x.3 (device3)")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931403/1745001 for more details on the above approach to saving command output in an array vs other approaches (readarray and mapfile are synonyms).

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Super solution Thanks